Blacklist the [oracle] tag
Following  Rename [oracle] to [oracle-database], the oracle tag should have disappeared. Unfortunately, it got resurrected and new questions are continually being created and tagged with oracle.
For the past few weeks, I've been re-tagging 5-10 questions per day from oracle to the appropriate alternative (mostly oracle-database, oracle-apex or oracleforms) but within a few hours another question will appear using that tag and the tag is never inactive long enough to be automatically deleted.
Please can we remove oracle and stop it coming back so that, hopefully, the correct tags start being used.

Actually, I think tag creation should not be so easy. In my opinion, a tag should be created with sufficient information amd usage guidance before being associated with any question.

@ray The problem is not creating the tag - someone has already done that (without a tag wiki or usage guidance). The problem is that, now the tag exists (and shouldn't), there is sufficient volume of questions that are being miss-tagged with it that it is not dying. Before [oracle] was retagged to [oracle-database] I would re-tag 1 or 2 questions per day that weren't about database to something more appropriate; now that [oracle] shouldn't be used I'm retagging five times as many questions - the solution to the previous problem has made a new problem that is (temporarily) worse.

With [[tag:oracle]] specifically, many questions had the tag without the tag actually existing. I've had to edit some of them at times (usually to retag something completely different) and if you edit one of those questions, you're asked whether you want to create the [oracle] tag because it's still there in the tag field. It takes a single person to make an edit and  just say "yes" for it to exist again.

While we wait for [tag:oracle] to be blacklisted, I've added a synonym [tag:oracle] -> [tag:oracle-database], as [tag:oracle-database] seems to be the most likely incorrect tag. I'm unsure what happened to the synonym, as it was created at the time of the prior request. Prior to my re-creating it, the system acted as if the synonym partially existed (e.g., a search for [oracle] is:a produced a couple hundred thousand entries). Now, search is messed up, as [oracle-database] is:a only produces 1,144 results whereas there are 152,637 questions.

I have blocked the oracle tag. Users will no longer be able to use it moving forward.

Please do [tag:api] next
